# Existe limite de níveis de subclasses para usar a função Where para consulta?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou trabalhando num sistema de dados estatísticos interno da minha empresa e me deparei com uma situação que nunca havia visto.

Estou consultando a API de um serviço e essa me devolve um JSON com muitas entradas e sub-entradas. Fiz a conversão deste JSON em classes do C# e comecei a trabalhar nos filtros das informações. Ocorre que se eu faço um filtro utilizando a função WHERE numa lista nos campos do primeiro nível o retorno é o correto. Entretanto, se faço isso em níveis internos, recebo uma exceção.

As classes dos objetos criados foram:

```cs
    public class Associations
    {
        public List<int> associatedVids { get; set; }
        public List<object> associatedCompanyIds { get; set; }
        public List<object> associatedDealIds { get; set; }
        public List<object> associatedTicketIds { get; set; }
    }

    public class DealnameVersions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public List<object> sourceVid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dealname
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public List<DealnameVersions> versions { get; set; }
    }

    public class HubspotOwnerIdVersions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public object timestamp { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public List<object> sourceVid { get; set; }
        public string requestId { get; set; }
    }

    public class HubspotOwnerId
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public List<HubspotOwnerIdVersions> versions { get; set; }
    }

    public class DealstageVersions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public object timestamp { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public List<object> sourceVid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dealstage
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public List<DealstageVersions> versions { get; set; }
    }

    public class CidadeDeInteresseVersions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public List<object> sourceVid { get; set; }
    }

    public class CidadeDeInteresse
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public long timestamp { get; set; }
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string sourceId { get; set; }
        public List<CidadeDeInteresseVersions> versions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public Dealname dealname { get; set; }
        public HubspotOwnerId hubspot_owner_id { get; set; }
        public Dealstage dealstage { get; set; }
        public CidadeDeInteresse cidade_de_interesse { get; set; }
    }

    public class Deal
    {
        public int portalId { get; set; }
        public int dealId { get; set; }
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
        public Associations associations { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }
        public List<object> imports { get; set; }
        public List<object> stateChanges { get; set; }
    }

    public class DealsModel
    {
        public List<Deal> deals { get; set; }
        public bool hasMore { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
    }
```

Os filtros estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```cs
reservationList.Where(x => x.properties.dealstage.value == funilItem.stageId);
```

Reparem na expressão passando pelo objeto properties, depois pelo objeto dealstage e comparando com o campo value.

Neste formato tenho falha. É gerada uma exceção com as seguintes informações:

> 'reservationList.FindAll(x => x.properties.dealstage.value == funilItem.stageId)' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, se fizer o mesmo formato de consulta só que nos campos no mesmo nível de properties, o processo é realizado com sucesso.

```cs
reservationList.Where(x => x.dealId == funilItem.stageId);
```

Agora pergunto. Existe alguma limitação com níveis de subclasses ou tem algo mais errado no meu código? Como devo resolver este problema?

Gostaria de pegar todos os Deals baseado no campo "value" contido dentro de properties -> dealstage -> value.

Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Não existe limitação. Especifique melhor o que você quer dizer com "ter falha" que talvez seja possível te ajudar.

Comment: Qual é a exceção?

Comment: Segue exceção e um print referente a todos os dados dela. Mas só para alinhamento, a lista não está vazia. Já conferi e ela conta com dados.

Comment: Talvez você esteja tentando acessar a propriedade de algum objeto que não foi instanciado